# Dereferencing not working for std::vector<std::vector<double> >

Tags: c++, vector, std

```
struct myS {
   std::vector<std::vector<double> > *A;
}
```

I want to access the elements of A using indices. I tried this (and also other versions) but it did not work.

```
struct myS test;   
std::vector<double> B = *(test.A)[0];
```

Comment: Why are you having the `std::vector` in a pointer?

Comment: There's almost never a valid reason to dynamically allocate an `std::vector`.

Comment: this is just a dummy struct I made here to deal with my case. The actual struct in my program has multiple fields, all pointers. I used pointers because they don't cosume lot of spaces. The function is suppossed to return multiple vectors,so I used struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reposition your brackets:

```
std::vector<double> B = (*test.A)[0];
```

Comment: The question has been modified. I realised a small mistake

Comment: Did you try my solution? You need to dereference the pointer to the vector first before accessing the vector via operator[]

Answer (score 2):

This compiles:

```
struct myS{
   std::vector<std::vector<double> > *A;
};
myS instanceOfMyS;

std::vector<double> B = (*instanceOfMyS.A)[0];
```

Note

- `struct myS` just declares a *type* of `myS`. To declare an instance of the type you need to add the `instanceOfMyS` afterwords.
- You also omitted the `<double>` in the declaration of `B`.

However the code above will take a copy of the first element in `*instanceOfMyS.A`. So you might want a reference instead.

```
std::vector<double>& B = (*instanceOfMyS.A)[0];
```

Finally, it looks a bit dodgy that you're using a pointer in your `struct` (with a pointer you don't allocate the memory to back the vector pointed to be A unless you explicitly allocate the memory, leading to access violations). You might want the following

```
struct myS{
   std::vector<std::vector<double> > A;
};
myS instanceOfMyS;

std::vector<double>& B = instanceOfMyS.A[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work :

```
myS myObj;
// Add some stuff in your vector(s) ...
...
// Access your vector
std::vector<double> B = (*myObj.A)[0]; // Don't forget here that it will copy the elements of the vector
```

Or if you want to access to an item into the second vector :

```
double B = (*myS.A)[0][0];
```

*Another question :* Why are you using a vector in the structure in this case ? In my own opinion, you should not have this pointer in your struct. It should be a value like :

```
struct myS{
   std::vector<std::vector<double> > A;
}
```

EDIT : small mistakes on dereferencing pointer resolved

Comment: In that case it is not very useful. This can be useful only if you copy an object already initialize (with items in vectors) because it will copy all the members otherwise there is no reason to do that.

Comment: Just realised that I have been returning pointer to local variable. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

You should write `(myS->A)[i]` to access the ith outer vector: rewrite your line as

`std::vector B = (myS->A)[0]`;

but note that this will take a *value* copy of the vector.

By the way, you will need to do `(myS->A)[i][j]` to access the jth element in the ith outer vector,

But why use a pointer in the first place?